# JTextField not editing JTextInput

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a simple program where there is a text input field and a label, and when you input something to the field it stores the input as "testInput" and changes the label to that text. I'm using Eclipse's Window Builder plugin for this, and it has worked fine before. What happens now is it will take the text in, but wont send it back out to the jLabel. Here is my code:

```
package interest;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TestWin {

String testInput;

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtTest;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TestWin window = new TestWin();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public TestWin() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    txtTest = new JTextField(); 
    //Change label when enter is pressed
    txtTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            testInput = txtTest.getText();
            txtTest.setText(testInput);
        }
    });
    txtTest.setText("test");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtTest = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtTest.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_txtTest.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtTest.gridx = 5;
    gbc_txtTest.gridy = 1;
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtTest, gbc_txtTest);
    txtTest.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("test");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTest = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblTest.gridx = 5;
    gbc_lblTest.gridy = 4;
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTest, gbc_lblTest);
}

}
```

I'm sure I'm making a really simple mistake, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: 'txtTest.setText(testInput);' makes no sense right after 'testInput = txtTest.getText();' - do you want to write 'lblTest.setText(testInput);' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("test");
```

at the begining of `initialize()` (or anywhere above `txtTest.addActionListener...`), and then replace

```
txtTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        testInput = txtTest.getText();
        txtTest.setText(testInput);
    }
});
```

for

```
txtTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        testInput = txtTest.getText();
        lblTest.setText(testInput);    //This line was changed.
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer would be significantly easier to comprehend if you recommended replacing exactly one line of code, instead of showing two six-line blocks, all of whose lines are identical except for one, which forces the reader to play a time-consuming game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: Added a comment next to the replaced line.

Comment: @VGR Sure, but the other lines provide context and save the answerer from playing the "I don't know where to make the change" game with the OP :P - But a comparison between what they have and they should change is also helpful ;)